# Container full rest height with scrollable content (Tailwind)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

On my page i need two containers both above each other with some margin.
The lower container needs to fill the rest of the screen but no more no less. Inside this lower container i have some content (like a navigation bar) which should be fixed there and visible all the time and another content i receive from a database so the content should be dynamicaly and scrollable. The problem is, that the scrollable content of the container always overflows the lower container and so goes out of the viewport. I need to stay the scrollable content in my lower container. I tried to fix this with several overflow-hidden/Overflow-auto fixes but without success. All the content should also have fixed positionings (margins/paddings) and widht and height.

Some of my Code:

Index.vue

```
<template>
 <div class="h-screen bg-gray-600 flex flex-col">

  <div
  class="flex h-56px w-auto z-1001 flex h-56px top-10 tablet:left-8 mb-16 object-  center tablet:object-left-top inline-flex justify-center items-center bg-grey-200 rounded-lg shadow-rb z-1001"
>
  <UpperContainer />
</div>
<div
  class="flex-1 h-full w-full tablet:w-420px mb-10 tablet:left-8 justify-center items-center bg-green-200 rounded-lg shadow-rb z-1001"
>
  <LowerContainer />
</div>
```

LowerContainer.vue

```
<template>
<div class="">
<FixedContentContainer class="">
  <FixedContent name="Example">
    <ScrollableContentContainer :scrollableContent="content"
      class="relative h-full w-full bg-blue-400 overflow-hidden"
    ></ScrollableContentContainer
  ></FixedContent>
</FixedContentContainer>
```

ScrollableContentContainer.vue

```
<div class="overflow-auto w-auto absolute h-full">
 <div v-for="content in scrollableContent" :key="content.name">
  <ScrollableContent
    :name="content.name"
  />
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a skeleton / working code for you in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ps06OpCCpp).

---

#### Read the below classes and understand. It's cool.

`flex-col` will seperate upper with the lower container

`space-y-8` is the space between upper and lower container

`min-h-screen max-h-screen` Set the main div to fit the page

`flex-1` on lower container will grow and consume the remaining space left i.e. h-screen (100vh) - h-24 (upper container) = lower container's height

`overflow-hidden` on lower container. Don't want the inside content to go outside this viewport

`flex-col` seperated navigation and scrollable container

`flex-1` on scrollable container to consumer the remaing height i.e. Remaining lower container's height - navigation(h-24) = scrollable container's height

`overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto` this will set the container to overflow by y-axis

---

```
<div class="flex flex-col min-h-screen max-h-screen bg-gray-50 space-y-8">
  
  <!-- Upper -->
  <div class="flex h-24 bg-gray-200">
    <div class="flex w-full justify-center items-center">Upper Container</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Lower -->
  <div class="flex flex-1 bg-gray-200 p-8 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 space-y-8">
      
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <div class="flex bg-gray-300 h-24">
        <div class="flex w-full justify-center items-center">Navigation</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Scrollable Content -->
      <div class="flex flex-1 bg-gray-300 p-8 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio minus et ea esse, quo officiis incidunt omnis laboriosam nesciunt quas ipsum deleniti repudiandae sint illo, odio commodi dolore impedit inventore. Maiores reprehenderit praesentium debitis mollitia impedit quasi qui aspernatur numquam atque, perferendis optio culpa! Quos placeat iure, deserunt unde ipsum repudiandae perferendis, doloribus fugiat qui aliquid iste praesentium, itaque officia. Obcaecati porro, consequuntur saepe maiores laborum laudantium eos nihil totam ea pariatur nam soluta neque nemo dolorem amet repudiandae laboriosam illum alias fugiat eaque minus. Provident, enim minima. Facere, obcaecati? Asperiores error blanditiis quos nostrum corporis nobis. Libero voluptate expedita maxime voluptates doloribus veniam quam vitae est minima corrupti dicta accusantium distinctio, aliquid tempora eum, laboriosam, nulla natus debitis cumque. Dolor velit possimus nesciunt deleniti quas dolorum neque cum reiciendis pariatur praesentium in qui voluptatibus provident a numquam, tempore distinctio impedit dicta non eos aut eveniet commodi doloremque. Cum, earum. Iste soluta perspiciatis debitis vitae ipsam doloribus aliquid voluptates repellat quae. Rerum enim eum nobis impedit molestias dolorum voluptatum animi exercitationem laudantium aut. Porro omnis excepturi harum reprehenderit doloribus ipsum. Rerum sed fuga amet totam, excepturi accusantium, quidem, perferendis nam doloremque expedita eligendi? Ratione harum exercitationem delectus iure asperiores? Nobis accusantium qui in. Laudantium, ducimus sit ipsum perspiciatis cumque vero? Soluta architecto eum ad suscipit beatae, nisi a, iusto dolore aperiam molestias voluptas pariatur perferendis facilis voluptatem optio nihil nulla explicabo saepe rerum corporis aliquid provident. Illum velit molestias totam? Esse, fugit tempora neque ipsum ea blanditiis culpa facere nobis soluta totam numquam voluptatum alias ad aperiam hic reprehenderit cumque quia, veniam incidunt illum fuga dignissimos. Animi ratione inventore doloremque. Laborum eaque ipsam nemo voluptates libero molestias, a consectetur accusantium consequatur mollitia. Deleniti, et? Vero aut laudantium alias aspernatur atque accusamus aliquid corporis architecto. Perspiciatis ducimus sed odio ex sint! Nihil rerum aut consequuntur reiciendis, officia amet soluta necessitatibus possimus. Dolorem excepturi in aperiam hic, rerum distinctio ut iure voluptate repudiandae tempore quidem facere quasi temporibus sapiente sequi eius eos. Dolorem cupiditate dolore in? Ipsa iusto quibusdam beatae consectetur ipsum nobis eum adipisci. Earum hic architecto voluptas fugit velit excepturi ab harum quibusdam nobis delectus nostrum explicabo, ut omnis? Praesentium. Fugiat quidem voluptates accusantium quisquam est, nulla inventore repellendus cumque doloribus rem nobis molestiae temporibus hic magni reiciendis. Nam earum commodi, et excepturi quae molestiae veniam nesciunt recusandae tenetur ducimus. Qui quas officiis iste. Libero a ipsam saepe accusantium illo velit obcaecati. Iure eligendi quasi voluptas labore provident nemo suscipit quis itaque sed libero earum autem nobis, atque omnis eius. Illum reiciendis, repellendus laudantium temporibus id blanditiis odio omnis ad quidem expedita error asperiores quo, hic culpa quisquam sequi maiores dolores fugit aut harum deleniti eum reprehenderit ex perferendis? Quidem. Qui odio, eius nulla minus libero nesciunt incidunt voluptatem repellat sapiente quae necessitatibus iusto unde nemo reprehenderit atque enim, vitae mollitia pariatur cupiditate ipsa? Iste incidunt excepturi accusamus a? Delectus! Aut dolores temporibus minus odio animi provident impedit repudiandae perspiciatis, eveniet autem accusantium suscipit expedita quas voluptatum veritatis nihil recusandae nemo possimus totam tempora, id sunt saepe dolor? Incidunt, laudantium! Harum eveniet dolorum cupiditate inventore recusandae perspiciatis dolorem aut suscipit optio dignissimos ut, nemo quod mollitia officia ab voluptatem nostrum ipsum quas? Rem similique, amet numquam reprehenderit optio harum repellat. Sequi, dolorum rem. Aspernatur eos sint, dolores neque sequi aliquid voluptates aliquam blanditiis repellendus eaque aperiam laborum corporis provident at culpa quasi, sunt voluptatem modi? Similique quisquam officiis minus ratione. Quasi asperiores natus libero doloremque earum labore perspiciatis nihil corrupti maxime. Voluptas ipsum rerum omnis, inventore quibusdam repudiandae, saepe facere at consectetur fugiat adipisci voluptatibus iure ea similique eveniet eligendi.
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are my official hero. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help. @Alex